# check if subarray is in array of arrays

Tags: python

I've got an array of arrays where I store x,y,z coordinates and a measurement at that coordinate like:

```
measurements = [[x1,y1,z1,val1],[x2,y2,z2,val2],[...]]
```

Now before adding a measurement for a certain coordinate I want to check if there is already a measurement for that coordinate. So I can only keep the maximum val measurement.

So the question is:

> Is [xn, yn, zn, ...] already in measurements

My approach so far would be to iterate over the array and compare with a sclied entry like

```
for measurement in measurements:
    if measurement_new[:3] == measurement[:3]:
        measurement[3] = measurement_new[3] if measurement_new[3] > measurement[3] else measurement[3]
```

But with the measurements array getting bigger this is very unefficient.

Another approach would be two separate arrays `coords = [[x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], [...]]` and `vals = [val1, val2, ...]`

This would allow to check for existing coordinates effeciently with `[x,y,z] in coords` but would have to merge the arrays later on.

Can you suggest a more efficent method for soving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick to built-in types (if not see last point in *Notes* below) I suggest using a `dict` for the measurements:

```
measurements = {(x1,y1,z1): val1,
                (x2,y2,z2): val2}
```

Then adding a new value (`x,y,z,val`) can simply be:

```
measurements[(x,y,z)] = max(measurements.get((x,y,z), 0), val)
```

*Notes:*

- The value `0` in `measurements.get` is supposed to be the lower bound of the values you are expecting. If you have values below 0 then change it to an appropriate lower bound such that whenever `(x,y,z)` is not present in your measures `get` returns the lower bound and thus `max` will return `val`. You can also avoid having to specify the lower bound and write:

  ```
  measurements[(x,y,z)] = max(measurements.get((x,y,z), val), val)
  ```
- You need to use `tuple` as type for your keys, hence the `(x,y,z)`. This is because lists cannot be hashed and so not permitted as keys.
- Finally, depending on the complexity of the task you are performing, consider using more complex data types. I would recommend having a look at [pandas DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) they are ideal to deal with such kind of things.